# Bootstrap fluid container vertical center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm struggling to center a DIV within a fluid-container (Bootstrap), and you may help me to resolve the issue.

I'd like to get the following result ; a full width block vertically centered on the page : [Image vertically centered block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpa4v.jpg)

I seeked for an answer through several topics, and managed to get it work ... until I use the "fluid" Bootstrap class in order to get fullwidth elements.

**EDIT** : I tried to use Flexbox, but the block is stucked on the top of the page : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpa4v.jpg)

```
html, 
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
.container-block {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: #FFF; 
}

.block {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: #313131;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="fluid-container container-block">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center block">AAA</div>

</div>
```

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% height not enoug for it

try to add `min-height : {somemeasure}px` to your css an change displaying table-cell to block

or you could try to use flexbox approach for your block:

```
.someselector {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lim Kayas, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, my block is still stuck on the top of the page after I try to use Flexbox. I updated the code in my question (first post).
Do you see where the problem is ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a bootstrap issue and can be acheived with pure CSS and absoulte positioning:

```
html, 
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
.full-page {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #f1f1f1;
posistion: relative;

}
.central-block {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: #323836;
color: #FFF;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;

}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jto8694c/1/)

Comment: Hi @JT91, thank you for your answer.
I tried using Flexbox, which can be helpful for my future needs.
I updated my code in my question post, which is not working yet. If you have some time, I'll be glad if you could check it out ;)

Thanks !

Comment: @Fl-0 This can be acheived withouth the need for flexbox - as above. Is there a particualr reason you want to use flexbox?

Comment: This is a part of a complete layout, including several backgrounds (one have to stay on the top, the other at the bottom, the central block mentionned in my question overlapping the 2 backgrounds), and I feel it could be easier to achieve with Flexbox.
I'm also on a learning path, and it could be a way to start using Flexbox.

But I may be totally wrong, of course. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Flexbox as suggested by Lim Kayas.
Thanks !